# checking null return from database using getSingleResult of entity manager

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I have to retrieve the db entry. I know the query I have written returns only one row. Therefor I am using getSingleResult. However when the query returns a null, I am not able to catch it. How do I solve this?
Here is the piece of code I have

```
       try {
            result = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM fields d WHERE d.fieldID = :fieldID", Field.class)
                       .setParameter("fieldID", fieldID)
                       .getSingleResult();

//manual null check only seems to work. But it seems tedious to check every DB column for null value :(

       if((result.getValsText() == null)){
                result = new Field();
                result.setValText("empty");

            }
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            result = new Field();
            result.setValText("empty");

        }
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For non-Id attributes you can either

- send a `COUNT` query before your regular query or better
- call `getResultList()` on your `Query`

`getResultList` will return an empty list if no results have been found. To get your single result, check whether the list is empty and call `get(0)` on it.

If the attribute is the `@Id` attribute, call `entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);` - `find` returns `null` if no results have been found and a single instance of your entity if it has been found.

EDIT- the last option is preferable for reasons of perfomance and readability. Use the second option (the list) where you cannot use the last one.

Comment: I seem to get a null bcos no records are found. I guess that is why NoResultException is not thrown?? then how to check this using getSingleResult?

Comment: @user900785 - well, that's the point - there is no way to check using `getSingleResult` exclusively - `try/catch` is the only thing you can do with it, so use it only where you are certain to find a result. For queries where it is not considered an error to find nothing, you can use one of the 3 options from my answer (you're better off using the third option where you can)

Comment: I have a different problem. I tried your suggestion and that is when I realised some of the column entries are NULL. Thus I get a null pointer exception. How do I check this?

Comment: @user900785 I am not sure I understand - what call exactly of which of the options causes the NPE? Please add the relevant code to your question.